# Bootstrap responsive table not scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I have cross platform app in which I displayed results in bootstrap table but while testing on small screens and even on chrome iPhone 4 & 5, some of the content of table is not fit totally on screen and table is not scrolling too. I tried number of solution from internet but no success.

```
 .table-responsive{
            width:100%;
            overflow-x:scroll;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            border:1px solid red;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }
```

Comment: have you changed .table-resposive class code there in bootstrap.css

Comment: If that table extends beyond the width of the page container, it will get clipped by Bootstrap. You will want to use Bootstraps built in responsive tables.

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution....

if table or some of its content is not working properly, then use `visible-xs`  or `visible-sm`  for more information on how to use these classes please visit this [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)